# Component loading on event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

My use case -

/view route  - call view component which makes service call and randers html formated line items iteratively in browser. - No issues. 
Further,
Each line item will have Edit button/link which will leverage user to edit the line item there only somehow by  loading  custom build edit component (Edit component is having a form containing one  tinymice editor and some other form components with a submit button). Once user click the Edit link, line item should be editable using respective instance of edit component and by saving need to update view with latest change and edit component need to go away. this behavior will occur every time for each line item.

Seems to me as creating and loading/linking Edit component dynamically in dom on click event of Edit link but not sure (which I guess may be tricky and complex) - what should be the right way to achieve this in angular 4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `input textbox` and a boolean flag `editMode`

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>
    <span *ngIf="user.editMode then editFirstName  else labelFirstName"> </span>
    <ng-template #labelFirstName>{{user.first_name}}  </ng-template>
    <ng-template #editFirstName>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.first_name"/>
    </ng-template>
    </td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td> 

    <button *ngIf="!user.editMode" (click)="user.editMode=true"> Edit</button>
    <button *ngIf="user.editMode" (click)="saveClicked(user)"> save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/a99vyouhDrllCojhBx7X?p=preview)**

Comment: This came in my mind by adding statically the edit mode form components, and hide 7 show toggle, but  its long list of view list items and edit mode need composition of couple of form fields including tinymce editor (including preview and math JAX features) with each line item which may memory intensive for 100+ line items. which I dont want, Any advise for that approach?